# 2 different number input factorial using function and for loop in php

Tags: php, function, factorial

I have a problem making a `C(m,n)=m!/n!(m-n)!` formula using a function and `for` loop in php, my code look like this:

```html
<?php
function factorial($m,$n){
 $facm=$m;
 for ($i=$m-1; $i >= 1 ; $i--) { 
  $facm*=$i;
 }
 $facn=$n;
 for ($i=$n-1; $i >= 1 ; $i--) { 
  $facn*=$i;
 }
 $faco=$m-$n;
 for ($i=$m-$n; $i >= 1 ; $i--) { 
  $faco*=$i;
 }
 return $facm/$facn*$faco;
}
}

echo factorial($bilm,$biln);
?>
```

but this code show wrong result, is it something wrong with my code? thank you for your attention.

Comment: what is 2 input factorial ? you want to find the factorial of 2 different numbers?

Comment: yeah, that's what i mean, is it possible to use function factorial($m, $n)? if it possible, how to make it? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do like below if it is stick to 2 parameters. If the parameters are dynamically change, then pass array to the function and do a foreach there.

```
 <?php
    $bilm = $_POST['bilm'];
    $biln = $_POST['biln'];

    function factorial($m,$n){

            $facm=$m;
            for ($i=$m-1; $i >= 1 ; $i--) { 
                $facm*=$i;
            }

            $facn=$n;
            for ($i=$n-1; $i >= 1 ; $i--) { 
                $facn*=$i;
            }

            $facmsubn = $msubn=$m-$n;
            for ($i=$msubn-1; $i >= 1 ; $i--) { 
                $facmsubn*=$i;
            }

            return ($facm/$facn)*$facmsubn; //By assuming (m!/n!)*(m-n)!; If it is m!/(n!*(m-n)!) then change the logic as per your formula
   }
          echo factorial($bilm,$blin);
    ?>
```

But why you need pass 2 parameters? Calling the function twice would make sense.

Runtime environment is here http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zkfs-21am

Comment: i'm trying to make this formula: C(m,n)=m!/n!(m-n)!, i use your suggestion, with my code, but the result is still not right.

Comment: I updated the code as per your formula. This should work. Also change the logic as per your need in the code and let me know.

Comment: i have problem to insert snippet code to this comment, i tried to use ctrl+k but that's not working, i tried 4 spaces before the line, it's not working either. try to use ">", not working too. how you inserting your code to a comment @siddiq? i want to show my code, but it's show horrible form.

Comment: just use the symbol ` before and after your code. you can find this left side to the key 1. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting for more formatting in comments. If you still struggle try update the code by edit your question.

Comment: You can use the same code i posted in the answer. Change the variable name as your wish. I gave an idea for your formula. You can work around and find your own logic if the formula and expected answer is wrong. Please follow the link

Comment: thank you, i don't check your link before, that's what i looking for.